# How can I point a route53 Apex Domain registry to a CloudFront Distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

When I try to add an **apex domain** to cloudfront Alternate Domain Names list, it throws the following error:
[Cloudfront error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWBmb.png)

I know my configuration works, because I am able to use the same domain with `www` as subdomain without any problem: [Cloudfront config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOTJ5.jpg)

And I'm sure route53 is not the problem, because I can create the Alias Record with no problem pointing to my CloudFront Distribution, but if Cloudfront doesn't let me add the **Apex Domain** on its list, it will reject and request.

*Note: an apex domain is an URL without the subdomain part, i.e. `domain.io`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is probably because your certificate in ACM has been registered for `www.domain.io` or `*.domain.io`. Such certificate **does not cover the apex domain** `domain.io`. From the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html):

> When you request a wildcard certificate, the asterisk (*) must be in the leftmost position of the domain name and can protect only one subdomain level. For example, *.example.com can protect login.example.com and test.example.com, but it cannot protect test.login.example.com. Also note that *.example.com protects only the subdomains of example.com, it **does not protect the bare or apex domain (example.com)**. However, you can request a certificate that protects a bare or apex domain and its subdomains by specifying multiple domain names in your request. For example, **you can request a certificate that protects example.com and *.example.com**

Typical soltuion is to create a new cerficate for both domains, `*.domain.io` and `domain.io`, or both `www.domain.io` and `domain.io`.

Comment: You were right. The SSL certificate `*.domain.com` doesn't include the **apex domain** ; my solution was to create another CloudFront Distro, that has the certificate for `domain.com` only.
Thanks!

Comment: I did that as well, created a certificate with domain.com and www.domain.com, and added alias A record that points to CloudFront distribution. But when I try to open domain.com, I get a certificate expired error, and { "message": "Forbidden" } error, but www.domain.com and direct cloudfront url work as expected.